# Decode base64 image recieved from internet in entity.getContent()

Tags: java, php, android, http

I am sending an Image in base64 format from PHP to Android.
On the android side, previously when I was entity.toString() it was working fine.
I was able to decode the result and create a Bitmap.
But now I want to keep track of how much the image has been downloaded. So I am using response.getHeaders("Content-Length") and entity.getContent();
From the InputStream I am reading it into a byte[] array. Howmuch ever I have read, I am converting it to a String. And appending to the final image_base64
The problem is I am not getting the same original base64 value in the final String.
Is there any other way to do this ?

```
       buf = new byte[totalSize];
        do {
            numBytesRead = stream.read(buf, numBytesRead, totalSize);
            String temp = Base64.encodeToString(buf,Base64.DEFAULT);
            image_base64 = image_base64 + temp;
            buf = new byte[totalSize];
            if (numBytesRead > 0) {
                downloadedSize += numBytesRead;
                dialog.setProgress((downloadedSize/totalSize)*100);
            }
        } while (numBytesRead > 0);
```

Comment: what is the size of your buffer? - the value of 'totalSize'

Comment: totalSize was the the value of content-length which was received from the server.

Comment: that's strange.. that means you're loading the whole content into the buffer on the 1st iteration and by the 2nd iteration there will be no more content...

Comment: the way read works is, it will put whatever data is avaliable into buf, starting from index <parmater2> and data of length <parameter3>
So, why do you think it will get over in the 1st iteration itself ?

Comment: well, if totalSize = the overall size of the content, then 'stream.read(buf, numBytesRead, totalSize)' in the 1st iteration will read from the 1st byte, until the totalSize byte, thereby reading the entire content in the 1st iteration... unless i'm missing something?

Comment: If you're looking for a more fluid loading, while notifying the user on each iteration, then the common practice is to use a limited sized buffer (i.e., 1024), then on every iteration, update a progress bar (on the UI thread) according to how much has been read so far, compared to the totalSize. The best practice here is to use an AsyncTask because it handles the threads for you.

Comment: I think if I change it to numBytesRead = stream.read(buf, numBytesRead,1024); It should work that way right ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Why even use base64 at all? Why not just output the image as-is in PHP and use the byte array you get on Android? Why waste band with and processing power?
2. The reason why the base64 strings don't match is probably because you **encode** it instead of **decoding** it when you receive it.
3. You can't just encode/decode a part of a base64 string, you need to have the whole.
4. Use `downloadedSize` instead of `numBytesRead` in `stream.read`, otherwise you'll overwrite the previously received data.

So if you really want to use base64:

```
buf = new byte[totalSize];
while(downloadedSize < totalSize)
{
    numBytesRead = stream.read(buf, downloadedSize, totalSize);
    if(numBytesRead > 0)
    {
        downloadedSize += numBytesRead;
        dialog.setProgress((downloadedSize/totalSize)*100);
    }
}
image_base64 = new String(buf);
// Now base64-decode it
```

Comment: Dude ! Thanks a ton !
Encoding the image increases the size. Correct. But if you echo the image directly it output some values in different encoding.